# react CSS form validation

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, validation

While making a form on react I downloaded some libraries and copied some example I ultimately went with one I made my self  but now my entire project has this  validation  that will stay no matter what I put in the project. Every time I click a button I get a tooltip and I have no idea how to control it.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

const FormRequest = () => {

   
    const formSubmitHandler = () => {
        
      console.log()
        }

    return (
        <div  >
            <div >
                <div >
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <span>CONTACT</span>
                                <span>US</span>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <form  onSubmit={(formSubmitHandler)}>
                                <div >
                                    <input 
                                        placeholder="NAME"
                                        name="name"

                                        onChange={''} value={''} required />
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                    <input 
                                        type="email"
                                        onChange={''} value={''}
                                        placeholder="EMAIL"
                                        name="email"
                                        required />
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                    <input 

                                        placeholder="CONTACT NO"
                                        name="contact"
                                        onChange={''} value={''}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                    <select 
                                        placeholder="REASON"
                                        name="reasonForContact"
                                        onChange={''} value={'onForContact'}
                                        defaultValue="">

                                        <option disabled={true} value="">Reason for Contact</option>
                                        <option value="">apple</option>
                                        <option value="">coconut</option>
                                        <option selected value="coconut">cocnutn</option>
                                        <option value="mango">Mango</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                                <div app-form-group >
                                    <input placeholder="MESSAGE"
                                        name="message"
                                        onChange={''} value={''} required
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                    <div >
                                        <input
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            checked={ ''}
                                            onChange={''} value={''}

                                            name="acceptTerms"
                                            required />

                                        <p> Do you agree to us saving your details for future us?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                    <button >CANCEL</button>
                                    <button >SEND</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>)
};

export default FormRequest;
```

Here is the output[image]

Comment: search `required` keyword in the code and remove those it will solve your problem

Comment: I wonder you are not aware of the required attribute for the form elements! And you are using react to build webpages. Make sure you are familiar with the basic concepts of HTML, CSS and JS before jumping into react!

Comment: The `required` keyword on your input elements causes the standard browser input validation. If you remove this attribute you won't see the standard browser form validation anymore

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "required" keyword from your input fields

Answer (score 2):

The `required` attribute is the HTML attribute, to have the form validation for inputs like phone number, email and so on. You should know about this.

Comment: Okay how do I  edit the tool tip it produces. is it possible?

Comment: It is not possible with the default tooltip in HTML, but you can create a custom tooltip using CSS